# Put images in array and display them

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I'm having some trouble to put my images in an array and show them in a canvas object.

Jscript snippet

```
canvas = document.getElementById('slideshow');
canvasContent = canvas.getContext('2d');

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');

for (var index = 0; index <= elements.length; index += 1)
{
    arrFoto[index] = elements[index];
}

canvasContent.drawImage(arrFoto[huidigeIndex], 0, 0);
```

This is a part of the html file

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="slides">
                  <img src="data/images/slideshow/3.png" />
                  <img src="data/images/slideshow/4.jpg" />
                  <img src="data/images/slideshow/5.png" />


              </div>
              <canvas id="slideshow" width="700" height="300"></canvas>

          </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to create an array, when you have a nodelist that can be accessed the same way ?

Comment: Oww, that's right. But now I'm getting a Type Error when drawing the image (canvasContent.drawImage(elements[huidigeIndex], 0, 0);

Comment: You have class="slides" on the div, not on the img items...  at least in your example.

Comment: getElementsByClassName will return a nodelist with your container div(s). `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');` this should return a list of your images.

Comment: Thanks @NickSlash, that solved it. I forgot I had a nodelist with my div inside of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've to iterate over the `<img>` elements inside your `.slides`, like follows

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('slideshow');
        var canvasContent = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');

        var arrFoto = Array();

        for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
           var imgs = elements[index].getElementsByTagName('img');
           for(var x = 0; x < imgs.length; x++)
              arrFoto[arrFoto.length] = imgs[x];
        }

        for(var huidigeIndex=0; huidigeIndex < arrFoto.length; huidigeIndex++)
            canvasContent.drawImage(arrFoto[huidigeIndex], 0, 0);
```

In your code, you've `index <= elements` (notice `<=`) which will make the last iteration of loop create `elements[index] is undefined` sort of error (JS arrays start with 0 index)

Answer (score 1):

`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');`

The previous code returns a `NodeList` that contains your `<div class="slides">`, not the images.

To get all images that are direct children of `.slides` elements, you could do:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slides > img');
```

*Note: You will have to wait until the images are loaded before drawing them on a canvas. Use the `load` event to determine when they are loaded. However, you will be fine if you execute the code inside a `window.load` event handler.*